# Is there a way to scroll images (ImageView) horizontally in a container on android device using appium

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

[image]

On an android device, I have an image container holding four images. See the highlighted container in the image above. The container is at the top of the screen, so, only that part of the screen is scrollable. The first image is fully displayed, the second is partially displayed. The third and fourth are hidden. I want to scroll through the container to get one of the hidden images.

I tried this:

```
AndroidTouchAction ta = new AndroidTouchAction(driver);
AndroidElement pic1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id='com.ryanair.cheapflights:id/iv_banner_bcg'])[1]"));  //first image in the container
ta.press(ElementOption.element(pic1)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(-70,55)).release().perform();
```

What the code is supposed to do is to grab the first element in the container, give it a negative offset on the x-axis so that it can move to the left, scrolling from right to left. The test passed, but the scrolling didn't happen, so definitely something was wrong but I am not sure what it is.

Who knows how I can achieve this?

This the source code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator`. `scrollableListResourceId` is the id of the container and pass text till which you want to scroll.

```
WebElement element =
                driver.findElement(
                        MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""
                                        + scrollableListResourceId
                                        + "\")).setAsHorizontalList().scrollIntoView("
                                        + "new UiSelector().text(\""
                                        + text
                                        + "\"))"));
```

You can also use content-description.

```
WebElement element =
                    driver.findElement(
                            MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                                    "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""
                                            + scrollableListResourceId
                                            + "\")).setAsHorizontalList().scrollIntoView("
                                            + "new UiSelector().description(\""
                                            + contentDesc
                                            + "\"))"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepak. I can't use the Text method because the elements are images, not texts. Also, the source code does not have contentDesc attribute, so I can't use that either. I have updated the question with the image of the source code for you to see. Is there a workaround?